# What are illegal/forbidden uses of the Holodeck?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology, holodeck

I remember the episode where Laforge's engineer, Reginald Barclay, uses the holodeck to strengthen his self confidence by creating holodeck clones (Musketeers) of the Enterprise crew, to fight against them, and Troi, as a Greek love goddess.

But it seemed to be forbidden to do this as far as I remember the episode. Also, I remember that Riker seems to use the holodeck to create bed bunnies. Of course it's not shown, but there is an episode where it's clearly insinuated that Riker seemed to be this space stallion.

Are there more details known than the one I remember? What type of Hologram programs are forbidden for distinct reasons?

Comment: There are a number of episodes that show that Riker avails himself of the softer pleasures of life more often then most.

Comment: @Xantec he is a sex-machine, he constantly recommends this love-planet for holidays, "Riga", as far as I remember. Would be another good question, what "type" of place this planet is. Garden of Eden without original sin :)

Comment: Although some may quibble whether there is a difference between a Holodeck and a Holosuite, in DS9 Quark certainly used them as eBrothels. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talk:Holosuite.

Comment: @Hauser - The pleasure planet _Risa_ that he often mentions has been depicted onscreen in numerous episodes...

Comment: Barclay also created holograms of the Voyager crew; I believe that was in the `Pathfinder` episode. Something which admiral Paris disapproved of ("I understand that you have been spending time with a holographic recreation of my son, among others. Frankly, I find that rather disturbing."), but which IIRC had no serious consequences for him in and of itself. His excessive Holodeck use and refusal to accept counseling for that was cited as a reason for temporarily removing Barclay from the Pathfinder project, however.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This was disturbing primarily because it was a recreation of his missing-and-possibly-dead son. I'm sure he wouldn't have cared much if Barclay was spending a lot of time with a recreation of someone less emotionally charged and insensitive.

Comment: @DampeS8N, That's a good point, but they had established the status of Voyager (through the Doctor's transmission across the Hirogen sensor network onto the Prometheus, shown in `Message in a bottle`) two years earlier, which I believe was one of the driving factors behind project Pathfinder. I don't recall for certain whether there was communication in the interim, but do believe there was, in which case Starfleet Command would be aware of Paris' status. Missing, yes, but presumably known to be alive.

Comment: Harkins' comment to Barclay in `Pathfinder` along the lines of "I'm not about to tell the admiral that we've found a way for him to chat with his son" would also seem to tip the scale slightly toward that Tom Paris' status was known before Pathfinder managed to establish the two-way communications link.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Nope, was some time before they were able to establish a regular connection to Voyager. In fact, the episode in question is how that connection is first established. 2 years is a long time. Tom could have been killed along the way. And in several alternate universes, was.

Comment: @DampeS8N, Good point. My reasoning was based around the (apparently mistaken) recollection that there was limited communications in the interim.

Comment: The term Masterbatorium comes to mind

Comment: You don't need to forbid any activities if you never allow the holodeck door to be locked.  Fear of being gossiped about is enough to make most everyone conform to whatever societal norms there are.

Comment: If a simulation was good enough, perhaps an unwitting victim could be drugged to later awaken in a holodeck-simulated scenario as part of some sort of deception plot. Or a holodeck could be used to rehearse a crime. But the overall plots would be criminal acts, and the holodeck merely a tool of their execution, so I don't see how a law need explicitly be written around holodecks. Recreating co-workers/crewmates as fantasy characters need not be forbidden, just left as an unwritten rule of poor taste and marker of disturbing behavior.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Reginald Barclay, the engineer you describe from the episode [Hollow Pursuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_Pursuits) is sent to Troi for counseling because his creation of altered, "fantasy" versions of his crew mates seems to indicate some emotional and social issues that would benefit from counseling from the ship's therapist (which is one of Troi's primary responsibilities).

There is nothing forbidden about his use of the holodeck, but that doesn't mean it isn't seen as troubling.

I don't believe there is anything listed as illegal or forbidden in the holodeck.  Worf, for example, uses it to practice combat, and in doing so "kills" simulated opponents with a bat'leth.  The safety protocols would prohibit most dangerous uses of the holodeck, as well.  Perhaps tampering with those protocols would qualify as forbidden/illegal, however.

Comment: I think too Reginald was sent to counseling because he was missing duty shifts because of what could be described as an addiction to the fantasy world. I think at one point Troi comments that the Three Musketeer fascimilies are private and shouldn't be taken seriously (of course her opinion changes when she sees her duplicate). So it would seem that what one does in a holodeck stays in the holodeck in most cases.

Comment: @Xantec - Unless you ask the computer to create a villain capable of defeating Data. B)

Comment: This is the only time I can remember that Star Trek suggests the dangers of the holodeck with regard to addiction and mental health.

Comment: @Xantec "What happens on the Holodeck, stays on the Holodeck" was actually mentioned onscreen by at least one of the characters at some point...  May even have been in _Hollow Pursuits_, I just know I remember hearing it

Comment: @JackBNimble: On DS9, Quark's nephew Rom became addicted to the Holosuite after his injury, spending almost all his time there for a while.

Answer (score 18):

The only thing that would be "illegal" about someone's use of the Holodeck would be if they somehow violated the safety or privacy protocols without the proper authorization. The Holodeck is definitely capable of creating lethal situations, and it requires the permission of multiple senior officers to bypass the safety systems.

If someone somehow "hacked" the Holodeck to bypass the safety systems without the proper permissions, that would probably be a no-no, especially since some of the possible uses for doing so would be quite sinister indeed (such as leaving the systems disabled, giving the next person who loaded up a swordfighting program a literal fight for their lives). By the same token, the Holodeck is controlled by the ship's computer, which has access to all the ship's data, and if someone got around security using the Holodeck to access confidential information, that's generally frowned on too.

Other than that, there seems to be a certain amount of privacy expected and given for most uses of the Holodeck. The command staff can, if they think it's necessary, bypass most security features of the ship, including unlocking doors, viewing personal logs, and loading private Holodeck programs. But, they only do so if there is suspicion about the person's mental state; for the most part, they leave well enough alone. As TNG is at best a PG show, it obviously doesn't go too deeply into the racier things you could do with a Holodeck, but just because humans have done away with greed doesn't mean they've abandoned ALL their baser instincts.

Comment: well, HAD they abandoned those they'd have gone quickly extinct :)

Answer (score 4):

I seem to remember in one of the books that it wasnt allowed/disaproved upon to create a copy of a living person inside the holodeck.

Comment: As Quark was attempting to do with Kira in one episode of DS9, for the nefarious pleasures of a paying customer (though further details elude me at the present)

Comment: Well, in *TNG:Booby Trap*, Geordi creates a replica of the Enterprise-D's propulsion systems designer, Dr. Leah Brahms, in order to help extricate the Enterprise from an artificial trap that has drained the ship's power. However, other things happen between LaForge and the holographic Brahms which the REAL Brahms objects to in a later episode.